# Mass Transit store and forward

Tags: masstransit

I am looking at Mass Transit documentation but those exemples I find are not completely beginner friendly, at least for me. Can I implement store and forward reliable messaging with MT? Should I use MSMQ or Rabbit MQ then? Any example would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a great series of blob posts to get started, look at

http://looselycoupledlabs.com/2014/06/masstransit-publish-subscribe-example/

There are subsequent posts that really detail how to do various other messaging patterns using RabbitMQ as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it looks promising :)